# UIViewController crash on new segue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am having connecting one out of many segue's in my storyboard. I finally got fed up and dragged an empty UIViewController on to my storyboard, and connected a button to it via the push segue. There are no methods, delegates, actions, attached to said button or view, yet I can not get the transition to occur.

This is the stack:

```
2013-10-22 13:11:10.070 Party Prioritizer[5445:a0b] -[UIViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa260020
2013-10-22 13:11:10.073 Party Prioritizer[5445:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa260020'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01a7c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0177d8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b19903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01a6c90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01a6c4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Party Prioritizer                   0x0002f81c -[WeddingViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 236
    6   UIKit                               0x00a239cc -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 156
    7   UIKit                               0x00a23a59 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0178f874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    9   UIKit                               0x004f1c8c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    10  UIKit                               0x004f1c18 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    11  UIKit                               0x005e96d9 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    12  UIKit                               0x005e9a9c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    13  UIKit                               0x005e8d4b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    14  UIKit                               0x0052f0cd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    15  UIKit                               0x0052fd34 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    16  UIKit                               0x00503a36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    17  UIKit                               0x004edd9f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01a058af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01a0523b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01a2230e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01a21b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01a2194b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x031899d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x031897fe GSEventRun + 104
    25  UIKit                               0x004f094b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    26  Party Prioritizer                   0x0001c46d main + 141
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x02e79725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any idea why my other 50 segue's work, yet I can't for some reason get this blank one to work?

Comment: Here is the thread list: http://i.imgur.com/Y2wIZiw.png

Comment: add your code. I think you are setting delegate to a view without a delegate property

Comment: All i did was drag a button onto a view, drag a new uiviewcontroller on to the screen, and create a push segue between the button and controller.

Comment: sure on your code you don't add something like `[segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];` before pushing your view ?

Comment: I was having trouble with this one button on this one view segueing. So i dragged a blank button onto the view, with a segue to a blank uiviewcontroller. No code behind anything except what xcode is making behind the scenes.

Comment: remove your view and try to create a new one

Answer (score 1):

Your view controller with the button on (`WeddingViewController`) is implementing `prepareForSegue:sender:`. Probably in that method you are not checking the segue identifier. Anyway, at some point in that method you are setting the delegate of a view controller which doesn't have a delegate and that is causing your crash.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push onto a ViewController... You should embed it in a NavigationController and then the push will work.